# How to pass Username and password to an application using shell script?

Tags: linux

I want to make script to login into application, its flow is like

1. Go to perticular directory,(My script=> cd /ld62_prod)
2. Give one command which will launch application(My script=> drv)
3. Application will launch and cursor will be pointing where i need to give username.
4. After giving username it will display next page prompting for password(now cursor is here).

Now my problem is I am able to reach till application launching, but not able to provide Username and password through script.

### My sample script is

```
cd cd /ld62_prod
drv
112233 #username
112233 #password
```

---

What I am doing wrong.

Comment: Give  your code here .

Comment: I would use `sudo` and the `sudoers` file to permit it; because I really don't want usernames/passwords stored in my scripts.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: then you must be absolutely sure your script is secure. If your script has a call to "ls" for example, one might prepended and extra directory to PATH, and put a `ls` script/binary in there to be called by your script and get root access. You must always use absolute paths, and/or don't trust PATH at all. Unset it and load the system's default. There are many other attack scenarios.

Comment: @jweyrich True enough, but still a better approach then storing username and password.

Answer (score 1):

**Without Security :**

You can use this :

```
 echo "User name: $0"
 echo "Password: $1"
```

And you can use the particular values using `$0` and `$1` .

Refer **[Shell script](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-special-variables.htm)** for more details .

**With Security :**

```
read -s -p "Password: " password
```

Under Linux (and cygwin) this form works in bash and sh. It may not be standard Unix sh, though.

For more info and options, in bash, type "help read".

```
$ help read
read: read [-ers] [-a array] [-d delim] [-i text] [-n nchars] [-N nchars] [-p prompt] [-t timeout] [-u fd] [name ...]
Read a line from the standard input and split it into fields.
  ...
  -p prompt output the string PROMPT without a trailing newline before
            attempting to read
  ...
  -s                do not echo input coming from a terminal
```

Comment: DON'T do that. Passing credentials to a script via arguments will expose them in /proc, apart from other security concerns.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `expect`, which is a standard tool that can communicate with interactive programs/scripts like yours. Its [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) says:

> Expect is a program that "talks" to other interactive programs according to a script. Following the script, Expect knows what can be expected from a program and what the correct response should be. An interpreted language provides branching and high-level control structures to direct the dialogue. In addition, the user can take control and interact directly when desired, afterward returning control to the script.